# SkylakeX Hyperthreading Bug and Microcode Update

Tags: microcode

I have a SkylakeX (i9-7940x) and I'm trying to figure out if the microcode update I have fixes this issue.  I haven't had any luck finding a specific reference to this fix on the Intel site and I'm wondering if Intel has even released a fix for the "X" processor.  Note this processor is model 85 / stepping 4 (`grep -E 'model|stepping' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u`)

Per this post https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/06/msg00308.html from June of 2017, there was no fix for model 85 processors at that time.

I have been experiencing very intermittent lock-ups and anecdotally turning off hyper-threading fixes the issue.  I'd like to find out if Intel has released a microcode update and if so, which release it's in.  If anyone knows this or can point me to references on the topic, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Skylake-X with the up-to-date intel-microcode package that addresses Spectre, etc. has the hyperthreading fix.